# stripe enable 3D secure in embeddable UI component

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I'm struggling in implementing the stripe 3D secure configuration in my embeddable card payment UI it dose not show the bank authentication popup.

Can anyone please provide any kind of sample for this.When we try to do the payment it show's this error message:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, and definitely don't post pictures of screen taken with a camera.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your client-side Stripe code that attempts to show the 3DS auth modal? Also what happens when you try to trigger that code? Do you get an error message in your developer console or anywhere else? Does anything visually happen while the page is attempting to show the popup?